# How can I solve this integration?

Tags: contour-integration

How can I solve this integration? Which method can I use to solve it?
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\{(K^2 +{K_1}^2 -2KK_1\cos\theta) +c\}^2 +d^2}$$

Comment: First - what are $k,k_1,c,d$? Second, what have you tried? I suggest trying using $z=e^{i\theta}$ and residue theorem or $u=\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$.

Comment: K, k1 are constant. They are not function of theta. I have tried by u = tan(\theta/2) and then contour theorem. But the final result is very complicated. Now I will try by your suggestions.Thanks